# Typescript generic that generates an interface of builder function types

Tags: typescript, interface, mapped-types

Given a Typescript interface:

```ts
interface Product {
  url: URL;
  available: boolean;
  price: number;
}
```

I want to create a generic type which given an interface can output a builder type:

```ts
interface ProductSteps {
  url: (data: unknown) => URL;
  available: (data: unknown) => boolean;
  price: (data: unknown) => number;
}
```

I have tried using the Record utility type to generate the Builder:

```ts
type Steps<T> = Record<keyof T, (data: unknown) => T[keyof T]>
type ProductSteps = Steps<Product>;
```

This works OK but it results in allowing any of the value types of Product as the return types:

```ts
type ProductSteps {
  url: (data: unknown) => URL | boolean | number;
  available: (data: unknown) => URL | boolean | number;
  price: (data: unknown) => URL | boolean | number;
}
```

Any ideas on how to restrict the return type of the builder functions to their corresponding type in `Product`?

Comment: Can't you just use a mapped type with `[ P in keyof T ]` to establish a relationship between keys and values? Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/jwg9Mm)?

Comment: `type Steps2<T> = { [ P in keyof T ] : (data: unknown) => T[P] };`

This one from your example is exactly what I need :) thanks

Comment: Yeah, whenever you think "corresponding" think "mapped" - it will instantly lead you to a solution :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks for the advice :)

Do you want to post an answer for me to accept?

Comment: Nah, probably plenty of duplicate targets lying around pointing with good reads on mapped types - will point to it if I dig out one

Comment: Can we do better than `data: unknown`?  Is the data type some known type, or can we make that be another variable on your generic?  Expanding @Oleg's playground: https://tsplay.dev/4WyDAm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) based on two generic values: an `ObjectType` like `Product` and a `DataType` representing the data that we are mapping.  For each key of the object type (`[P in keyof ObjectType]`), the corresponding value type is a function that takes the data and maps it to the object value for that key (`(data: DataType) => ObjectType[P]`).

```
type Steps<ObjectType, DataType> = {
  [P in keyof ObjectType]: (data: DataType) => ObjectType[P]
};
```

Calling this with your `Product` and an arbitrary `SomeDataInterface` like this:

```
type Test = Steps<Product, SomeDataInterface>;
```

resolves to:

```
type Test = {
    url: (data: SomeDataInterface) => URL;
    available: (data: SomeDataInterface) => boolean;
    price: (data: SomeDataInterface) => number;
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/vW4kvm)